# Facebook Apps with C# and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, asp.net-core

I would like to develop a Facebook app. I am only familiar with C# and .NET Core. Will I experience any limitations since the business SDK is not available for .NET? I am not very familiar with Facebook development.

Comment: Limitations in what sense?

Comment: Any amount of unavailable features

Comment: Why would there be any unavailable features? The SDKs are built around a web API that operates over HTTPS.

Comment: Ok. I'm just confused about why they wouldn't include documentation for C#.

Comment: Probably because they don't have a .NET SDK, as you said. Their API is documented though.

Comment: Have a look on this... https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk

Answer (score 1):

The Business SDK relies on the Graph API, which is also public.

Directly accessing the API is very, very common, the documentation is decent, and going that route is web-based, which works from any client you've got.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Answer (score -1):

I have used the Facebook Csharp SDK recently to upload hour long videos. This is a process that runs every hour and uploads a video. During this development, I found there are bugs in the SDK and I fixed it and uploaded a pull request. But I am not sure if anyone maintains that branch. But you can get the uploaded code from my github here

https://github.com/hoquem1/facebook-csharp-sdk

If you want the parent branch, you can see where I forked it from.

You need to get your permission and Tokens properly. Directions are in facebook for developer page. For Facebook Graph Api, I used the v8.0. If you need some documentations here are some useful links below. Follow the breadcrumbs..

https://developers.facebook.com/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/getting-started

This should get you started.